# Replace # with entry.title

Tags: craft3, entries, replace

Good morning and thank you in advance. How can I replace '#' with the entry.title. I have tried everything and I keep getting hash errors. Current code is this:

```
<h3>{{ wordBoldTitle|replace({'#':'<strong class="font-weight-extra-bold">{{entry.title}}</strong>'} )|raw }}</h3>
```

Trying to concatenate the  with the entry.title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twig, you never want to use delimiters inside other delimiters (e.g. `{{ ... {{ ... }} }}`).

Here's how you would format it instead:

```
<h3>{{ wordBoldTitle | replace('#', '<strong class="font-weight-extra-bold">' ~ entry.title ~ '</strong>') | raw }}</h3>
```

What we're doing here is using Twig [concatenation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators) (via the `~` operator) to combine our first string (`<strong class="font-weight-extra-bold">`), whatever string `entry.title` results in, and then our second string (`</strong>`).

Alternatively we can use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) to achieve this; however string interpolation requires double-quotes, so to do this we'll need to escape the double quotes already in our string:

```
<h3>{{ wordBoldTitle | replace("#", "<strong class=\"font-weight-extra-bold\">${entry.title}</strong>") | raw }}</h3>
```

---

I also changed your replace filter from using a hash (e.g. `{'#':'xxx'}` to the simpler (at least in this case) comma-separated parameters. The hash works well if you need to replace multiple items, but the comma-separated parameters looks cleaner in my opinion when you only need to replace one item. You can find more about the replace filter formatting [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#replace).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you